# React redirect after login not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying using react-router and redux to build my react app. However, I am unable to get the url to route back to the dashboard post login. Can somebody please point out my mistakes?

```
const form = reduxForm({  
  form: 'login'
});

class Login extends Component {  

    handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
      this.props.loginUser(formProps);
      var token = cookie.load('token');
      if(token !== undefined){
        const location = this.props.location;
        if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
          browserHistory.push(location.state.nextPathname)
        } else {
          browserHistory.push('/')
        }
      }
    }

    renderAlert() {
    if(this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div>
          <span><strong>Error!</strong> Authentication error</span>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
        {this.renderAlert()}
          <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <Field name="username" className="form-control" component="input" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <Field name="password" className="form-control" component="input" type="password" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary submitButton">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {  
  return {
    errorMessage: state.auth.error,
    message: state.auth.message
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loginUser: () =>
    dispatch(loginUser);
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(form(Login));
```

My `loginUser` function is as below:

```
export function loginUser({ username, password }) {
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.post(`${AUTH_URL}/obtain-auth-token/`, { username, password}, {
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": cookie.load('csrftoken')
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                if('token' in response.data){
                    cookie.save('token', response.data.token, {path: '/'});
                    dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});
                } else{
                    console.log("Error condiction: " + response);
                    errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR);
            });

     }
}
```

This is my first react-redux project so the mistake might be pretty elementary. Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your issue appears to be with handling your async call - in your `handleFormSubmit(formProps)` function you have the following two lines:

```
this.props.loginUser(formProps);
var token = cookie.load('token');
```

You are dispatching your action that will be running your async function (`loginUser(formProps)` does a post using axios), and then you immediately try to consume the results of this async function by loading the token that it should have stored in a cookie upon success. This does not work because immediately upon running an async function, JavaScript will not wait for the results but instead will return to your `handleFormSubmit` function and run the rest of it through completion. I am sure that if you `console.log`'d your `token` it will be undefined (assuming there were no cookies before running the app) - the function continued without waiting for your async function.

So I know two good options that you can use to fix this:

1. Simple, standard solution: You run `dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});` upon the success of your async post - have this action creator result in a change in your state held by redux (ex: `loginFlag`). Include `loginFlag` as a prop in your `Login` component (include it in your `mapStateToProps` function). Finally, include a `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` lifecycle function to your `Login` component and have it handle the route change. Include something like:

```js
componetWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.loginFlag) {
    var token = cookie.load('token');
    if(token !== undefined){
      const location = this.props.location;
      if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
        browserHistory.push(location.state.nextPathname)
      } else {
        browserHistory.push('/')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or:

2. Heavier solution using another package: You can use the npm package react-router-redux (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), to do a push to browserHistory within your redux action at the end of your async call - doing so will require you to setup its middleware and hook it up to your redux store. More info: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#api

   - I would definitely recommend looking into react-router-redux. If you do not want the browserHistory functions available in your redux actions, then it is very simple to setup in your project (don't need to make changes to the store or add its middleware) and it allows you to track your url path within your redux state which can be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I used the second approach and it worked seamlessly. one additional question, is it right to call the `browserHistory.push` method in the async call via handleSubmit ? Is this the 'react' way or should I be calling this in some other function/location?

Comment: Excellent question! I feel that the more 'react' way of handling this process is the first option that I suggested - having a minimum amount of side-effects occur because of the async call, and simply have it update a flag/store the API response in your redux state, and have `componentWillReceiveProps` react that that (dispatch another action, change route, whatever). However, using react-router-redux's browserHistory within your action does simplify things..
I read a recent article that goes more into this and concerns about using overly-powerful middlewares like thunk:

Comment: http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/?utm_campaign=React%2BNewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_source=React_Newsletter_58